# .Net Client Timeout

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, timeout

In my Windows application I try to connect to SQL Server 2008 with following code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.KargarBandarConnectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select IsAdmin from Users where UserName=@UserName And Password=@Password", connection);
SqlDataReader dataReader = null;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserNameTextBox.Text.Trim());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordTextBox.Text);
try
{
    connection.Open();
    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (dataReader.HasRows)
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            IsAdmin = dataReader.GetBoolean(0);
        }
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
    else
    {
       FMessageBox.ShowWarning("error");
        UserNameTextBox.Focus();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (progressForm != null)
        progressForm.Close();

    FMessageBox.ShowError(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (dataReader != null)
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataReader.Dispose();
    }
    if (connection != null)
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Everything works properly, but sometimes I get the following error:

> timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool ...

How can this be solved?

Comment: increase your connection time out time.

Comment: Are you sure every other place you connect to the SQL Server you disconnect/close/dispose the connection when you're done with it?

Comment: My network is small and little information is received from the server. I do not really know why I get this error!

Comment: "And Password=@Password". Somewhere, a kitten dies every time someone passes a plaintext password as an SQL Parameter :(

Comment: Try using the `using` statement to handle the disposal of your `IDisposable` objects. This would include (at least) `connection`, `command`, and `dataReader`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting this exception is because you have exhausted your connection pool and the number of "available" connections in your application.

Every time you open a connection, one is pulled from the connection pool if possible, or a new one is created if not.

However, to prevent galloping usage of connections, a limit of 100 (I think this is configurable) exists, and if you try to use more than 100 simultaneous connections, the code will *not* create new ones, and instead sit down to wait for one to be returned to the pool, and in this case you get a timeout if it sits too long.

So, for the particular example of code you've shown, I would:

> Close the connection *before* I show an error messages to the user

However, unless 100 users are seeing the error message *and leaving it there* at the same time, it is unlikely the code you've shown is the cause of this problem.

Other than that, I would go through the entire application and ensure you don't have any connection leaks other places.

This particular type of exception can occur in one spot even though the problem is somewhere else. Example: A report is leaking an open connection every time it runs, and you run it 100 times successfully, then someone tries to log in, and the exception occurs in the login form.

Answer (score 1):

That happens if you either:

- leak connections (leaving them for GC to deal with rather than disposing them)
- just have too much happening, such that the pool is exhausted

The first is the most common, and I *expect* it relates a lot to the fact that you are over-complication your error handling. This makes it easy to miss, and hard to spot that you've missed it. The code shown looks OK, but it would be far preferable to use `using` blocks for all the `IDisposable` elements, rather than `finally`. Also; don't keep the connection while you show modal things like the message box, unless you *need* the connection afterwards. Frankly, a lot of benefit here could be made by cleanly separating the UI and data-access code, then there is *not temptation* to stick a message-box in the middle of a database query.

However! To be explicit, I believe this code is the **victim** of some other code that is hogging connections. Look at your **other** data access code for the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code to look something like this. Implement `using` blocks. The other answers here are very important, be sure to understand them.

```
bool res=false;
try
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.KargarBandarConnectionString))
    using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {       
        cmd.commandText = "Select IsAdmin from Users where UserName=@UserName And HashedAndSaltedPassword=@PwdHash";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserNameTextBox.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PwdHash", SaltAndHash(PasswordTextBox.Text));     
        connection.Open();
        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result!=null)
        {
            res=bool.Parse(result);       
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }   
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{   
    if (progressForm != null){progressForm.Close();}
    FMessageBox.ShowError(ex.Message);
}

if(res==false)
{
    FMessageBox.ShowWarning("error");
    UserNameTextBox.Focus();
}
```